# Search for special characters, SymbolHound.com is down, alternative

Tags: search, search-engine, website, special-characters

Do you know pages similar to SymbolHound.com which contain the use of special characters searches? Some alternatives and why this site stopped working? Google cannot cope with searching for phrases containing slashes, for example if I would like to search for the "/quit" command then it cannot be done.